# Bad Behavior after upsizing MDB to SQL Server (no upsize_ts in Table)

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2003, upsizing

maybe you could help, i didn't find any proper solution for my problem:

Working Environment:

```
Access 2003
SQL Server 2008 R2 Express
Database (based on Access 2003) containing a few dozens of Tables, related to each other:

 - Table "Customers" FOREIGNKEY CustomerID
 - Table "Invoice-Header" FOREIGNKEY InvoiceID, with Relationship to Customers-->CustomerID with DELETE/UPDATE Trigger inside MDB
 - Table "Invoice-Detail" FOREIGNKEY CNT, with Relationship to Invoice-Header->InvoiceID with DELETE/UPDATE Trigger inside MDB
 - Table "Delivery-Header" FOREIGNKEY DeliveryID, with Relationship to Customers-->CustomerID with DELETE/UPDATE Trigger inside MDB
 - Table "Delivery-Detail" FOREIGNKEY CNT, with Relationship to Delivery-Header->DeliveryID with DELETE/UPDATE Trigger inside MDB
```

Why i ask? :

Well, i upsized this Database many times (with Entries from our Customers) to a SQL Server Database without any problem, the database is from our software we deliver, but getting filled with informations of the customer who's using our software (creating Customers, creating Invoices, creating Delivery Notes), but this time a Customer of us gave us the Database for upsizing to a SQL Server Database and it would not work:

What i did --> what happend:

```
Attempt #1: Upsized as Usual --> Delivery-Header / Delivery-Detail has no upsize_ts but Invoice-Header / Invoice-Detail had (Normally all Tables had upsize_ts field after Upsizing)

Attempt #2: Upsized again after fixing missing Customers in Customers Database --> Delivery-Header / Delivery-Detail has upsize_ts but not Invoice-Header / Invoice-Detail

Attempt #3: Upsized again after copying everything into our Base of this Database (fresh created) --> Delivery-Header / Delivery-Detail has no upsize_ts but Invoice-Header / Invoice-Detail
```

What could cause such behavior that upsize_ts Field is not created inside the SQL Database without aborting Upsize-Assistant? Normally, every Table had a "upsize_ts" Field (when checked in Upsize-Assistant, and that was checked, since a few Tables had upsize_ts but some not)

Normally, the Upsize-Assistant will abort if theres an error with the Database but this time it converts all Tables from Database without throwing an error but missing upsize_ts fields.

If you'll need further informations please write to me, its driving me nuts that this time i've got deep trouble to convert with Access 2003 to SQL Server.

Comment: I did not understand your Attempts logic: if Attempt one is successfull, why would you need to run it another time? And upsize_ts fields only makes sense if the database will still be used by MS-Access. Otherwise they are of no interest.

Comment: Attempt #1 wasn't successful, since Delivery-Header had no "upsize_ts" Field in Table but Invoice-Header had a "upsize_ts" field in it. Normally every Table had a "upsize_ts" Field after Upsizing with Option (Add TimeStamp Field)